# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference | Not Sure How The Reference Is Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Context:

I'm trying to build a feature in my MVC Application where an Employer can take an Application submitted by a Student, and convert the information in the Application to create an Employee. However, I'm running into the Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference error.

Controller:

```
     public ActionResult Onboard (int id)
        {


            var application = db.Applications.
                Include(a=>a.JobPosting.Employer).
                Include(a=>a.Student)
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ApplicationID == id);
         

            return View(application);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Onboard([Bind(Include = "ApplicationID,JobPostingID,StudentID")] Application application)
        {


            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Employees.Add(new Employee()
                    {
                        Student = application.Student,
                        JobPosting = application.JobPosting,
                        Employer = application.JobPosting.Employer

                    });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Employees");
                }
            }

            return View(application);
        }
```

View:

```
     @model InTurn_Model.Application
        
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Onboard";
            Layout = "~/Areas/Employers/Views/Shared/_Employers.cshtml";
        }
        
        <h2>Onboard</h2>
        
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Onboard","Applications",FormMethod.Post,null))
    
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input id="StudentID" type="hidden" value="@Model.StudentID" />
    <input id="JobPostingID" type="hidden" value="@Model.JobPostingID" />
    <input id="EmployerID" type="hidden" value="@Model.JobPosting.EmployerID" />

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentID, "StudentID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <span>@Model.Student.FirstName @Model.Student.LastName</span>
            </div>
        </div>

     

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobPostingID, "JobPostingID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <span> @Model.JobPosting.Position</span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Hire" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
    
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

When I run a debug, the breakpoint on

`return View(application)`

stores the relevant information from the 1st Onboard controller.

However, the breakpoint on `public ActionResult Onboard([Bind(Include = "ApplicationID,JobPostingID,StudentID")] Application application)`, the 'application' is storing values of 0 for ApplicationID, JobPostingID and StudentID. It's not null technically, but they aren't the correct values.

My question is, what am I doing wrong that the controllers are not passing the correct data?  How do I fix this issue?

Is there a better way to achieve this?

I am incredibly new to MVC, and this is the first application that I'm building from the ground up. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please show us your `Model` class also so we can get more information on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I didn't need to use the [HTTPPost] or [ValidateAntiForgerty]. My thought was treating this like a create- but I guess because I'm not actually creating new data- rather transferring one piece of data to another- I don't need to use that.

Here's what I wound up doing:

```
 public ActionResult NewHire(int id)
        {
            var application = db.Applications.Find(id);
            db.Employees.Add(new Employee()
            {
                StudentID = application.Student.StudentID,
                JobPostingID = application.JobPosting.JobPostingID,
                EmployerID = application.JobPosting.Employer.EmployerID

            });
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```